# Highlight searched word

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In Symfony2, how will i highlight the word i search from the search box :

// Search Twig:

```
{% block body -%}
    <h1>Results of "{{ find }}"</h1>
    {% if entities%}
        {% for entity in entities %}
            <table class="record_properties">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>            
                        <td>><a href="{{ path('onequestion_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.question }}</a></td>
                    </tr>                 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
    {%else%}
        <td>No Results found</td>
    {%endif%}

{% endblock %}
```

//searchController :

```
public function searchAction() {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $find = $data['search'];

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
                        'SELECT p.id, p.question
        FROM EpitaEpitaBundle:questionanswer p
        WHERE p.question LIKE :data')
                ->setParameter('data', "%$find%");


        $res = $query->getResult();


        return $this->render('EpitaEpitaBundle:questionanswer:search.html.twig', array(
                    'entities' => $res,
                    'find' => $find));
    }
```

// I am getting the searched result but i want it to be highlighted...

Comment: You could write a custom filter that takes text, and replaces found search terms with html. For example: `{{ entity.question|highlight(term_array) }}`

Answer (score 3):

You could, probably, do something like:

```
<td>><a href="{{ path('onequestion_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.question|replace({find: "<span class='highlight'>" ~ find ~ "</span>"}) }}</a></td>
```

And then create a class in css:

```
span.hightlight {
  /* Whatever you want to do with highlighted elements*/
}
```

Another option would be to write your own filter in PHP.

Comment: Check this link: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html 
It contains all the info about creating own filters.

Comment: The first one will not work, HTML will be encoded. You can add the `|raw` filter to make it work, but it's not a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to create your own filter as suggest by @Mindastic.

For that you will need a custom Twig extension, follow [this cookbook entry](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) to do that.

You will need to mark the output as [safe HTML](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping) to make it work.

Last, but not least, for security reason, I encourage you to use PHP `strip_tags()` function on the input value to avoid injection.

Comment: // I used :

{#<a href="{{ path('onequestion_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"><span class="highlight" style="background: yellow">{{ entity.question }}</span></a></div>#}

// This is highlighting the whole line and not the specific spearched word